# Python sklearn GridSearchCV: parallelization is not working

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scikit-learn

I encounter some problems using `GridSerachCV` from `sklearn` package and parallelization.

To see if it was coming from my data, I tried to perform the same kind or processing on the `iris` dataset embedded in `sklearn`.
I try to optimize a SVM classifier for different parameter values. When I set `n_jobs=1` there is no problem, it is working well (the following code runs in about 0.5s). But if I just change `n_jobs` to other values, then it runs indefinitely (I did not let it run several hours, but after more than 10 minutes I still don't get any result).

Here is the code with `n_jobs=3`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import grid_search

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)

parameters = {'C': [0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,1.0],\
             'coef0': [0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9],\
             'degree': [2,3,4],\
             'gamma': [0.0,0.1,0.2]}

clf = SVC(random_state=0, max_iter=-1, probability=False,shrinking=True, verbose=False,\
          class_weight='auto',tol=0.0001, kernel='poly')
gridsearch_RF = grid_search.GridSearchCV(clf, parameters, n_jobs=3,  cv=2, verbose=0)
gridsearch_RF = gridsearch_RF.fit(X,y)

print gridsearch_RF.best_score_
print gridsearch_RF.best_params_
```

I also tried with another classifier (RandomForest) and I get the same problem.

Does anyone have had the same problem?

(I use WinPython-64bits-2.7.9.5 and sklearn version 0.16.1)

Comment: Maybe try making it more verbose so you can get a little more info diagnosing the problem

Comment: I second Ryan. Set verbose=3 and you will see what is going on at each search step

Comment: Nothing is displayed even with verbose=3, although all my four procs seem to be used.

Comment: Maybe try `RandomizedSearchCV`

Comment: any solution since ? I have the same problem